# AWS Cognito - logged in session with multiple app clients

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

We have a cognito user pool that is shared between multiple app clients.

We are using AWS JS SDK to connect to the pool using react in 1 application.
However, the other is using the Cognito Hosted UI Page login form.

When we login using react, we get all the tokens and user info in the react app, however, if we go to the cognito login page on the same browser, it doesn't show the user as logged in user.

Is there any endpoint we have to call using JS SDK to make sure the user is actually logged in so
that going to the Cognito Hosted UI Page would show the user as logged in? Or do we need to create a cookie or something to make sure the Cognito Hosted UI Page is able to detect the user as a logged in user?

Expected behavior:

When the user is logged in using AWS JS SDK, we need to show the user as a logged in user on the Cognito Hosted UI Page page as well.

Comment: Hi, what's OOTB?

Comment: OOTB - Out Of The Box ( Cognito Hosted UI Page )